# How can I fetch and pass the result to the next fetch in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I fetch the `version` and `languages` and pass them to `getChampions` function

```js
const [version, setVersion] = useState(0)
const [languages, setLanguages] = useState([])
const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = useState('')
const [champions, setChampions] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  getVersion().then((version) => setVersion(version))
    .then(getLanguages().then(languages => {
      setLanguages(languages)
      setSelectedLanguage(languages[0])
    }))
    .then(getChampions(version, selectedLanguage).then(champions => setChampions(champions)))
}, [])
```

I'm getting the default values from the initialization of `useState` where `version = 0` and `languages = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so if you `setState` and then call a function with the `state` immediately after you are not guaranteed to get the current `state` value.  @Yadab's answer resolves this but calling `getChampions` with the variables from the response rather than the variables from the state.

My personal preference is to use a separate hook to respond to changes in the state.  It also seems like `getVersion` and `getLanguages` don't depend on each other and can be run simultaneously rather than one after the other.

```
const App = () => {
  const [version, setVersion] = useState(0);
  const [languages, setLanguages] = useState([]);
  const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = useState("");
  const [champions, setChampions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getVersion().then(setVersion);
  }, []); // run once - include [setVersion] if using eslint

  useEffect(() => {
    getLanguages().then((languages) => {
      setLanguages(languages);
      setSelectedLanguage(languages[0]);
    });
  }, []); // run once - can include deps [setLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] for eslint

  useEffect(() => {
    // only execute if both version and selectedLanguage have already been set
    if (version && selectedLanguage) {
      getChampions(version, selectedLanguage).then(setChampions);
    }
  }, [version, selectedLanguage]); // run whenever version or selected language changes

...
```

Comment: Thanks your code reduced the times it takes to fetch data and it runes smoother

Answer (score 1):

You can use async await in a separate function to fetch the version and language and use the fetched version and language to fetch the champions data. Take a look at below example.

```js
const [version, setVersion] = useState(0)
const [languages, setLanguages] = useState([])
const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = useState('')
const [champions, setChampions] = useState([])

const fetchData = async () => {
  const versionData = await getVersion();
  setVersion(versionData)
  
  const languageData = await getLanguages();
  setLanguages(languageData)
  setSelectedLanguage(languageData[0])
  
  const championsData = await getChampions(versionData, languageData[0])
  setChampions(championsData)
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [])
```

Comment: i used you code its working for the version but i got the `languages[0] = ''` i tried using `selectedLanguage` also gives me `''`

Comment: Were you getting the languages with your code?

Comment: i solved it it was `const championsData = await getChampions(versionData, languages[0])` i changed it to `const championsData = await getChampions(versionData, languageData[0])`

Comment: Oh Yeah! I missed that. I updated the code so that it will be useful for others.